# Cannot access stream arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:144091332251:table/users/stream/2019-06-05T08:00:51.428

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I want to trigger lambda function as soon as new records are inserted into `dynamodb` or existing record is updated. For the same, I'm using aws `dynamodb` stream features. I trying to do so but it throws me below error.

```
Cannot access stream arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:144091332251:table/users/stream/2019-06-05T08:00:51.428. Please ensure the role can perform the GetRecords, GetShardIterator, DescribeStream, and ListStreams Actions on your stream in IAM. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: c88c1297-438b-11e1-a338-e57e98788b7c)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your IAM role misses necessary policy to access the streams.

Please follow the further steps if you are still getting the same error-

1. Open your role that your DynamoDB stream lambda is using. You can find in in your Lambda function webpage at the bottom.

[image]

2. Open this role in IAM console and click on **Attach Policy**.

[image]

3. Add the following policy to it- "AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole"

This policy has the required permissionss that you need to be able to fire streams lambda. See, the JSON doc attached with this policy -

[image]

I hope, now it should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution.

Comment: In my case I had create a role and a policy using aws cli, but for some reason, policy was not assigned to the role